# Does Google bot crawl entire site if there is a redirect

Tags: php, seo

I have a website that redirects a user to the login page after a three page views.  Will google bot be able to look at all of my pages or will it be redirected as well. If so, how can I get around this.

I found this answer in a question about googlebot,

```
if((!$user->uid) || (!strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Googlebot"))  ||      (!strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"MSNBOT")) ){
//  redirect
else{
// don't redirect
}
```

Would this work?

Comment: Google bot gets redirected. And what do mean by `Will google bot be able to look at all of my pages` ?

Answer (score 3):

1. Do not serve up different content to search engines then you do your users. That's called cloaking and is a great way to get banned.
2. You should use "[first page free](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3863/how-does-experts-exchange-get-away-with-tricking-google-users)". It's what sites like Experts Exchange use to allow Google to crawl their restricted content.

Comment: Google bot will act *just* like a real user. If they detect that you're trying to work around it, it'll have major negative effect on your SEO

Comment: Thanks for the information.  The content is the same for anyone, but after 3 page views I want them to sign up. So this will still get me banned. I'll take a look at "first page free" and see if that works. Thanks.

Comment: This my understanding of"first click free".A site will be considered "first click free"if a user clicks the link, from google, and sees the page without signing up.I set it up so that that after one page view you would have to sign up.I used cookies.I checked google analytics & it showed some of my pages didn't get index after I added the redirect.My guess is that, the google search results lead to a sign in page instead of the page, because of the cookies.How can I allow a  user to see the page if they get the link from a google search.Is it possible to know if a user comes from google.

Answer (score 0):

Google Bot gets redirected and it will take content from the redirected page into its database as for the original URL.